# Is it OK to do work related projects involving site ripping while at home? (Contains technical jargon)

Tags: company-policy, websites, off-site-events

I just need to bring up a minor predicament that I need to discuss related to my job. I was assigned a task that involves removing unnecessary external web service snippets in my work place's web sites. While a seemingly simple task, I have noticed some of the snippets are placed in parts of the website that are dependent on external cloud applications that could possibly break if any changes are made. What is even more frightening is that my job does not have any real blue green deployment strategy, version control system, or testing/revision system to remap and verify new revisions will work.

With me and  my team also aware of the problem, we are having strong anxiety about changing anything on the site. I did discuss with my coworkers on my team about the idea of setting up a stopgap prototype of a blue-green deployment system from my home over the weekend. However I just realized that I'm not sure if they have  informed my boss of this idea and I promised to get this project ready by Monday.

Since all ip addresses are logged when people access any of the companies web services. My boss seems to have a strong aptitude of quickly judging who is accessing the services including some former coworkers. Since the project requires a site rip to complete and not being sure my boss is aware of this weekend home project.

I'm not sure if I would be breaching protocol and might get accused of stealing content or doing something in an insecure manner. (This is going to be ripped to a local MAMP apache server on my personal external hard drive which will later be transferred to my work PC.) Would it be wise to still proceed with this task from home? I don't want to disappoint my coworkers yet I don't want to break any protocol.

Comment: Including former coworkers? How does the idea of copying intellectual property of your company to your personal hard drive without permission to go over it with people that don't even work at the company not raise any red flags with you?

Comment: You shouldn't have to "rip" the site in order to set up the staging server. Explain how the staging server will give you the ability to do controlled changes. As it is now, you can't really do any changes since the live site will be affected. That's obviously no good, but you have to explain it to the boss, not try to do something on a "weekend project".

Answer (score 4):

Ask your boss, inform him of the details and get permission before you do it.

I don't see why this couldn't be done at work though, I set up labs all the time. So if I was your boss I would refuse. But you may have better luck.

Comment: I'm not the most experienced with it and afraid it would use too much of my payroll time at work and cause performance complaints if it does not work as planned. I just want to test it at home out of courtesy to save them expenses.

Comment: payroll time is when you're supposed to do work related stuff. This is a task you have been given, not a volunteer project of your own unrelated to work.

Comment: This is a volunteer project to make everyone on my team (including myself) less fearful of making alterations to the site that was assigned to be made.

Comment: do volunteer work with volunteer (made up) data, or ask your boss if you can use company data. But in saying that, a virtual lab for this sort of thing is something that you should already have at work. So making one is perfectly understandable, and your boss should realise the benefit of having one at work.